# how to create an Android Studio working vector drawable from an svg file

Tags: android, svg, vector, graphics

I try to get some country flag vector drawables working in Android Studio.

I use the [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) and drop one of the svg flag files from [flags-of-all-countries](http://www.bartneck.de/2012/11/20/flags-of-all-countries-in-vector-format/). The svg2android is now producing a 13MB xml. What is wrong?

Then I try a svg flag file from [flag-icon-css](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/tree/master/flags/4x3) and dropping it onto svg2android and that seems to first work with warnings and in Android studio the vector image is invisible. (including this vector code down below)

Using Android Studio Assets studio to generate the vector xml file for both the above svg files does not work because of unsupported tags something.

My Question is how to create a country flag Android vector xml drawable?

Here´s the vector xml from [flag-icon-css](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css/tree/master/flags/4x3) that ends up in Android as invisible or missing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="100"
    android:viewportHeight="100">

    <group
            android:scaleX=".9375"
            android:scaleY="0">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#bd3d44"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:pathData="M0 0h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0
78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0
78.77h972.81v39.385H0z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:strokeWidth="1"
            android:pathData="M0 39.385h972.81V78.77H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0
78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0zm0 78.77h972.81v39.385H0z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#192f5d"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:pathData="M0 0h389.12v275.69H0z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:pathData="M32.427 11.8l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.853 0l3.541 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735H93.74zm64.856 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.269-6.734-9.269 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.896h11.457l-9.269 6.735 3.54
10.896-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.542-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zM64.855 39.37l3.54
10.896h11.458L70.583 57l3.542 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.269 6.734L59.126
57l-9.269-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.896h11.457L135.435 57l3.54
10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734L123.978 57l-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.896h11.458L200.29 57l3.541 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734L188.833
57l-9.269-6.734h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.896h11.458L265.145 57l3.541
10.897-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734L253.69 57l-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54
10.896h11.457L329.997 57l3.54 10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734L318.54
57l-9.27-6.734h11.458zM32.427 66.939l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.853 0l3.541
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735H93.74zm64.856 0l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.269-6.734-9.269 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54
10.896h11.457l-9.269 6.735 3.54 10.896-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734
3.541-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734
3.542-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zM64.855 94.508l3.54 10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734
3.542 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.269 6.734 3.54-10.897-9.269-6.734h11.458zm64.852
0l3.54 10.897h11.457l-9.269 6.734 3.54 10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734
3.541-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54 10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.541
10.897-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.897-9.269-6.734h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54
10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.541 10.897-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734
3.542-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.897h11.457l-9.269 6.734 3.54
10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zM32.427
122.078l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.853 0l3.541 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735H93.74zm64.856 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.269-6.734-9.269 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.896h11.457l-9.269 6.735 3.54
10.896-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.542-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zM64.855
149.647l3.54 10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.542 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.269 6.734
3.54-10.897-9.269-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.897h11.457l-9.269 6.734 3.54
10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.541 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.897-9.269-6.734h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.541
10.897-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.542-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54
10.897h11.457l-9.269 6.734 3.54 10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734
3.541-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:pathData="M32.427 177.217l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268
6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.853 0l3.541 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735
3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735H93.74zm64.856 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.269-6.734-9.269 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.896h11.457l-9.269 6.735 3.54
10.896-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.542-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zM64.855
204.786l3.54 10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.542 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.269 6.734
3.54-10.897-9.269-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.897h11.457l-9.269 6.734 3.54
10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.541 10.897-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.897-9.269-6.734h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.897h11.458l-9.27 6.734 3.541
10.897-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.542-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54
10.897h11.457l-9.269 6.734 3.54 10.897-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734
3.541-10.897-9.27-6.734h11.458z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#fff"
            android:fillType="evenOdd"
            android:pathData="M32.427 232.356l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268
6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.853 0l3.541 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735
3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734 3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735H93.74zm64.856 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.269-6.734-9.269 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.458zm64.852 0l3.54 10.896h11.457l-9.269 6.735 3.54
10.896-9.268-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.541-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458zm64.855 0l3.54
10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541 10.896-9.27-6.734-9.268 6.734
3.54-10.896-9.269-6.735h11.457zm64.855 0l3.54 10.896h11.458l-9.27 6.735 3.541
10.896-9.269-6.734-9.27 6.734 3.542-10.896-9.27-6.735h11.458z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: It says: `Please report wrongly converted SVGs by filling an issue on github.`

Comment: Your right of cource

Answer (score 0):

Well, not necessarily responding to this question, but this library saves my life a few months ago, maybe it can solve your's problem:

https://github.com/almosr/android-svg-code-render

Warning it's mandatory that the SVG file as a size. you can check this option when saving from Illustrator.